# how to pass java 8 lambda expression for IStatus Object to Logger api (Custom Logger)

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, eclipse-plugin, java-8

I have a logger API which accepts a Supplier where IStatus is a eclipse IStatus Object.

```
IStatus status = new Status(Status.ERROR,"plugin","Message",e);
```

Example:-

Interface:

```
void log(Supplier<IStatus> statusSupplier);
```

Implementation:

```
public void log(Supplier<IStatus> statusSupplier) {
    if(statusSupplier.get() == null) {
        return;
    }
    handle(statusSupplier.get());
}
```

How to call this API using client code. please suggest how am I create a lambda expression for above Method.
or is this method is correct for java 8 lambdas.please to suggest some idea?

Answer (score 3):

[Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) is one of the functional interfaces of Java 8. It has one method (`get()`) which has no argument and returns an instance of the generic parameter.

So in your case, `Supplier<IStatus>` should return an `IStatus` instance. You can achieve this with the following code:

```
log(() -> new Status(Status.ERROR, "plugin", "Message", e));
```

**Explanation**: This lambda expression will be an implementation for the `get` method of the `Supplier` interface. The `()` indicates that the method takes no arguments. When your code consists of only one line of code, you don't need a `return` statement, as the result of this line is returned by default.

The logging implementation with a supplier will help by not executing the code until it is really needed, e. g., when you execute some complicated functions when calling the `log` method.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way to do this in Java 8 lambdas?  like using another functional interfaces ?

Comment: can i use a lambda as log((Status.ERROR,"plugin","Message",e)->Status:new);  using constrctor and method reference?

Comment: @YogendraSharma Unfortunately, `log((Status.ERROR,"plugin","Message",e)->Status:new);` will not work. The reason is, that the lambda expression must apply the signature of the method it's implementing, which in this case does take no argument.

Comment: I agree for Supiler<IStatus> case it will not work, but if i want to implement method as log((Status.ERROR,"plugin","Message",e)->Status:new); then how to do this ?

Comment: When you can change the `log` method, you could do the following:
`public interface MySupplier {
  IStatus get(String status, String plugin /*more arguments...*/);
 }

public void log(String a, String b  /*more arguments...*/, MySupplier s)`

and call the method like this:

`log("status","plugin"  /*more arguments...*/, Status::new);`